# UIWebView load html from local but images from remote using webservices call

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Here is my code to load a html file and now inside the html I want to load Images dynamic.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Myfile" ofType:@"html"];
NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSString *resourceURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
resourceURL = [resourceURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"//"];
resourceURL = [resourceURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"file:/%@//",resourceURL]];

[self.webView loadData:htmlData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:baseURL];
```

This is how my html will look like. Here instead of image.png I want to use webservice call to fill in the image.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="image.png" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Also I would like to use `SDWebImage` for caching the image.

Answer (score 0):

Preprocess your HTML string with a regular expression that converts the "img src ..." text to be a full URL.